# Changing a for loop to a dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I get how to do regular comprehension style conversions for `For` loops, but this, I can't wrap my head around.

I know that normally you would change the lines 3-5 into one line, but is it possible to include the empty list in the comprehension?

The code is

```
    text = input().lower()
    dict = {}
     for x in text:
      if x.isalpha()
       dict[x] = text.count(x)
    print(dict)
```

I don't even know where to get started.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in function.

To convert the loop to a dictionary comprehension, change `dict[key] = value` to `key: value`, then follow it with the `for` loop and `if` condition.

```
text_dict = {x: text.count(x) for x in text if x.isalpha}
```

Note that Python has a standard library function `collections.Counter()` that does this.

```
from collections import Counter

text_dict = Counter(filter(str.isapha, text))
```

Comment: The most straightforward method in this case!

Comment: OMG that works. I did that originally but it didn't work. Dont know what i did that was different.

Comment: Just to chime in with my two cents, the first implementation (and the one in OPs) does way more work than need-be. `x: text.count(x)` gets evaluated and replaced for every duplicate letter in `test`. If you wanted to go with a non-comprehension solution, I would use a defaultdict. `text_dict = defaultdict(int); for x in filter(str.isapha, text): text_dict[x] += 1`

Comment: @flakes If you're concerned about performance, the Counter method is best.

Comment: @Barmar agree 100%

Answer (score 0):

By referring to the dictionary comprehension posted by @Barmar, another way to do so is using dictionary comprehension and `set`:

```
result = dict((x,text.count(x)) for x in set(text.lower()) if x.isalpha)
```